# Excel VBA Open and close a Folder

Tags: vba, excel

So I know how to open a folder within an excel vba macro, but I want to be able to close it as well. Any thoughts? This is what I'm using to open the folder:

```
Shell "Explorer.exe *file path*"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Process ID, stored in `vPID`, to kill the application when you’re done with it. all you have to do is invoke the `TaskKill` command with the same `Shell function`.

```
Dim vPID As Variant
vPID = Shell "Explorer.exe *file path*"

'Perform actions here

'// Kill file
Call Shell("TaskKill /F /PID " & CStr(vPID))
```

Comment: I have other code/tasks in between when I open it and when I want to close it. Would I have to name the file path or just kill?

Comment: @FruitUser just kill it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys, but I decided to ditch the idea since it was getting really complicated. (@Omar I tried send keys but it ended up closing my workbook, even placing the command after code to show/open the folder window)