# Close folder opened through Explorer.exe

Tags: excel, shell, vba

It's a bit of a silly question, but how do you close a folder through Excel VBA ? Below the code to opening it,

```
Shell "Explorer.exe \\sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\folder", vbMinimizedFocus
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764615/excel-vba-open-and-close-a-folder) solution with the process ID unfortunately does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code loops through all opened Explorer windows. So you can use that to match against the `LocationURL` and get the window handle `hWnd` and use Windows API `SendMessage` to close the window.

```vb
Option Explicit

'for 64-bit Excel use
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Long) As LongPtr
'for 32-bit Excel use
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Long) As Long


Const WM_SYSCOMMAND = &H112
Const SC_CLOSE = &HF060

Public Sub CloseWindowExample()
    Dim sh As Object
    Set sh = CreateObject("shell.application")

    Dim w As Variant
    For Each w In sh.Windows
        'print all locations in the intermediate window
        Debug.Print w.LocationURL

        ' select correct shell window by LocationURL
        If w.LocationURL = "file://sharepoint.com@SSL/DavWWWRoot/sites/folder" Then
            SendMessage w.hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0
        End If
    Next w
End Sub
```

Note that the `LocationURL` path begins with `file://` and that all backslashes `\` in the path are converted to slashes `/` as shown in the example.

To make it compatible with both 64 and 32 bit Excel you can use

```vb
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
        (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Long) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Long) As Long
#End If
```

Note that one of these will be marked in red as compile error but the code will still run.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the detailed solution, but there's an issue with `SendMessage w.hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0` . While the code find the folder window in question, the previous sequence does not close it and I do not know why, it just iterates past it. I'm not sure it can help, but the code runs on a laptop with a 32 bit Office 2013 Professional Plus running on a French 64 bit Win 7 Enterprise version.

Comment: Well, that's odd. You can try if `w.Quit` works instead. And check the values of the variables `w.hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE`?