# Excel VBA - Closing a specific File Explorer window out of multiple open File Explorer windows

Tags: excel, vba

Cell A3 contains folder path. Cells below contain file names with extensions. Upon selecting a cell below, my Excel macro opens that file's location in File Explorer and out of multiple files in that folder selects this particular one, which can be seen in Preview. When next cell containing another file name is selected on the spreadsheet, another File Explorer window opens, even though it's the same path from A3.  Looking for a line of code to add which will first close the first File Explorer window, before opening a new one. The code needs to be closing that specific File Explorer window from cell A3, out of multiple open File Explorer windows. Code I have so far

UPDATE: Running below codes, but it does not close the existing opened folder, just opens yet another:

```
If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 5 Then

Call CloseWindow

Shell "C:\Windows\explorer.exe /select," & Range("A3") & ActiveCell(1, 1).Value, vbNormalFocus 'this works, but opens NEW folder every time
```

and in separate Module:

```
'BELOW GOES WITH Public Sub CloseWindow() FROM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649663/close-folder-opened-through-explorer-exe
Option Explicit

''for 64-bit Excel use
'Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
'    (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Long) As LongPtr
''for 32-bit Excel use
'Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
'    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Long) As Long

'To make it compatible with both 64 and 32 bit Excel you can use
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
        (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Long) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Long) As Long
#End If
'Note that one of these will be marked in red as compile error but the code will still run.


Const WM_SYSCOMMAND = &H112
Const SC_CLOSE = &HF060

Public Sub CloseWindow()
    Dim sh As Object
    Set sh = CreateObject("shell.application")

    Dim w As Variant
    For Each w In sh.Windows
        'print all locations in the intermediate window
        Debug.Print w.LocationURL

        ' select correct shell window by LocationURL
'        If w.LocationURL = "file://sharepoint.com@SSL/DavWWWRoot/sites/folder" Then
        'If w.LocationURL = "Range("M1").value" Then
        If w.LocationURL = "file://K:/ppp/xx/yy/1 - zzz" Then
            SendMessage w.hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0
        End If
    Next w
End Sub
```

UPDATE 2:
I am now thinking however, that probably the best solution would actually be not to close the file explorer and then open it, but rather for the code to identify that there is already an open file explorer window with path from cell A3 and neither close it nor open a new one, but rather just select the new file corresponding to the new cell being clicked on in already opened file explorer window with path from cell A3. Can anybody think of a way to do that?

Comment: @BigBen - Shell "C:\Windows\explorer.exe /select," & Range("A3") & ActiveCell(1, 1).Value, vbNormalFocus 'this works, but opens NEW folder every time

Comment: @BigBen - Thanks, done

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - can you help with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution (not my own) that implements a WMI query against a 'Win32_Process' Class. The code here closes any explorer.exe instances. While I don't fully understand it, I did test and found it works.

```
Sub CloseWindow()

    Dim objWMIcimv2 As Object, objProcess As Object, objList As Object
    Dim intError As Integer

    Set objWMIcimv2 = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set objList = objWMIcimv2.ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='explorer.exe'")

    For Each objProcess In objList
        intError = objProcess.Terminate
        If intError <> 0 Then Exit For
    Next

    Set objWMIcimv2 = Nothing
    Set objList = Nothing
    Set objProcess = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job for you. If the folder is not open it will open it, otherwise it will activate it and will bring it to the front.

In case you want to select a file in the folder, you should modify this a bit and use `oWinOpen.Quit` to close the window and then re-open it. Shell's behavior when opening a folder simply is different from when selecting a file in the folder too.

```
Sub OpenFolder(strPath As String)
    
    Dim bFolderIsOpen   As Boolean
    Dim oShell          As Object
    Dim oWinOpen        As Object
    Dim Wnd             As Object
    
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    
    bFolderIsOpen = FALSE
    
    For Each Wnd In oShell.Windows
        If Wnd.Document.Folder.Self.Path = strPath Then
            Set oWinOpen = Wnd
            bFolderIsOpen = TRUE
        End If
    Next Wnd
    
    If bFolderIsOpen = FALSE Then 'open it for the first time
        Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & """" & strPath & """", vbNormalFocus)
    Else
        oWinOpen.Visible = FALSE
        oWinOpen.Visible = TRUE
    End If
```